# Stripe SCA Compliance

Tags: api, stripe-payments

I’m currently maintaining an app that’s used in Denmark. We use Stripe API to make payments from the server, the flow goes: user inputs CC, app side tokenizes card and sends to server, server sends payment to stripe through API.

I’m trying to figure out what needs to change to be work with SCA, I read the docs for using payment intents but we’re not using that api.

Will we need to pass something along to user from the server for the extra layer of authentication?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: In order to comply with SCA, you'll need to migrate to the PaymentIntents API. There are two options: [Manual Confirmation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration) which is more like the Charges flow you're used to, and [Automatic Confirmation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration/automatic-confirmation) that makes use of asynchronous events and webhooks. Either option will let you perform the steps necessary for SCA.

Comment: Ah yes the more I research the more inevitable it seems we need to switch.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the PaymentIntents API there is also the new SCA-ready Checkout V3 if you don't want/need to use Elements.:

1. Create the Checkout Session early on the server side

   ```
     const session = stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
       payment_method_types: ['card'],
       customer: stripe_customer_id,
       success_url: `https://API/v1/cart/${cart.id}/pay`,
       cancel_url: `https://API/v1/cart/${cart.id}/cancel`,
       line_items: [{
           name: 'Bike',
           description: 'Super cool bike...',
           images: 'https://UI/product.png',
           amount: 100,
           currency: 'USD',
     }]
       payment_intent_data: {
         capture_method: 'automatic', // or 'manual'
     }});
   ```
2. Redirect user the the Checkout on the front

   ```
     const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
   ```

   3a. User will be redirected from stripe-hosted checkout to /v1/cart/${cart.id}/pay
    You will want to fulfill the order at this point.

   3b. Alternatively setup a webhook and handle incoming notification

NOTE: If you decide you to go with capture_method=manual you will want to capture the payment like so:

```
 stripe.paymentIntents.capture(session.payment_intent)
```

Reference: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server